# Power bi KPI visual - Goal (Blank) (+Infinity%)

Tags: powerbi, dax

For a KPI visual I created 2 measures:

```
Current = 
    CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table1'[ID]),
    ENDOFMONTH('Table1'[Période backlog])
)
```

and:

```
CALCULATE(
    [Current],
    DATEADD(
        DateTable[Start of Month].[Date],
        -1,
        MONTH
    )
)
```

But when I add the measures the following way:

```
Value:      Current
Trend Axis: Start of Month (from a Date table with a relationship to Table1)
Target:     Backlog Target
```

The target does not show the previous month, but the same value as "Current"

When I click on the Menu of the Visual and select "Show as table" I get:

| Start of month | Current | Backlog Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2023 | 123 | 123 |
| 01/09/2023 | 100 | 100 |
| 01/10/2023 | 132 | 132 |

The "Backlog Target" column is the same as the "Current" column.

And when I change the code to -2 month:

Backlog Target =

```
CALCULATE(
    [Measure],
    DATEADD(
        DateTable[Start of Month].[Date],
        -2,
        MONTH
    )
)
```

I get the table:

| Start of month | Current | Backlog Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2023 | 123 | 123 |
| 01/09/2023 | 100 | 100 |
| 01/10/2023 | 132 |  |

What I ould like to have is the following table:

| Start of month | Current | Backlog Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2023 | 123 | xxx |
| 01/09/2023 | 100 | 123 |
| 01/10/2023 | 132 | 100 |

Is there a solution to this?

Thank you in advance for any help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `Current` measure as it is, and update your `Backlog Target` to:

```
Backlog Target = 
  CALCULATE(
    [Current],
    DATEADD('DateTable'[Date], -1, MONTH)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This just keeps every measure blank for some reason

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: Hello, thanks again. This now seems to populate all rows. The problem now is that it displays the same value as "Current", If I change the DATEADD function to -2 month, it removes the "Backlog Target" for the latest month, and populates all others with the same value as Current anyway. I dont know if what I mean is very clear.

Comment: I can update the question if it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Is the issue now - Target = Current? What does your date table look like? And could you update the question with sample data (Table1) please?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. I updated the question to match the current state of my issue

Comment: Please use `DATEADD('DateTable'[Date], - 1, MONTH) `

Comment: I get the same result, sorry.

Comment: Could you share a sample pbix please?

Comment: I will try to create a sample. My dataset is very big.

Comment: I created a sample file. How do I upload it, so you can check it out?

Comment: Uploaded to a public share, like OneDrive, GoogleDrive etc...

Comment: Hello, there you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iE_bJvgkmvoyQZNWr_sZ0AFMN7-D9fDX/view?usp=sharing. Note: File was created with Power BI Desktop Report Server

Comment: Thank you for the pbix. If I modify your `Backlog Target` from `DateTable[Date].[Date]` to `DateTable[Date]` then it works (as above answer). Give it a go.

Comment: Ahhhh, Sorry, I thought I had to put the".[Date]". I did not know I could leave it out.. Noob mistake. Thanks a lot for your help :).